# Time in the Kitten Game

Tags: kittens-game

How is time measured in the kittens-game?

In particular, Winter lasts 100 days, the stock tells me, how long(seconds) my supplies will last, but I've no Idea how many seconds 100 days are.

Comment: possible no, but answered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is measured in ticks.
In the game, there are 5 ticks per second (or one tick every 200ms), and there are 10 ticks to an in-game day.

This means each day is 2 seconds long in real time. So 100 days will be 200 seconds, or 3 minutes and 20 seconds.

Note: You may experience slight variations in the time depending on the performance of your machine, but on most modern machines and browsers this should be broadly accurate.

*Source*: being a JavaScript game it is quite easy to look at the code directly to figure this out. If you want to take a look yourself, the main clues for figuring this out are in the `calendar.js` and `game.js` files.