# How fast do kittens gain experience?

Tags: kittens-game

I've seen that kittens [grow skills with experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184469/should-i-force-my-kittens-to-do-the-same-job-forever?lq=1), but I couldn't find at what rate kittens gain experience.

How much XP does a kitten gain in a year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is in the [source](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/village.js?v=1.1.3.5):

```
var learnRatio = this.game.bld.getEffect("learnRatio"); //line 652
var skillRatio = 0.01 + 0.01 * learnRatio; //line 653

kitten.exp += skillRatio; //line 679
```

I think this is done each tick, so 5 times a second (iirc). So each second you gain at least 0.05 experience, depending on the `learnRatio`. The `learnRatio` is increased by the academy, 0.05 per academy. For example, 10 academies yield a `learnRatio` of 0.5, and you'll get 5*(0.01 + 0.01 * 0.5) = 0.075 experience per second.

To answer your question (how much exp in a year): there are 400 days, and 10 ticks per ingame-day ([source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/188964/80141)). That means that you'll get

```
4000 * (0.01 + 0.01 * learnRatio) experience
```

per in-game year.

Comment: So, in early game, without academies, it takes 100 ticks (5s) to gain 1XP, and a year yields 40XP. Later in the game, 20 academies double that figure. Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In early game, without academies, it takes 100 ticks (5s) to gain 1XP, and a year yields 40XP.

It takes 100XP to for a kitten to get to Novice at a job (1.25% bonus), which is 2.5 ingame years, or 33 minutes. Left at it, she will reach Adequate after an additional decade (2h45 total) … and Master after 2 more centuries, i.e. 2d.

Later in the game, experience is gained twice as fast with 20 academies, thrice as fast with 40 academies, etc.